# Titles in geom box plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I want to put x and y labels for my qqplot graph. But it was not sucessful. My graph takes the column headings instead of the assigned titles.  Can somebody tell me where the mistake is ? My script is as follows.

```
setwd("F:/Research/Fieldwork SL-data/Seed predation and seed no/Seed No")
seednumber<-read.csv(file="seed number -analysis 3.csv", header=TRUE, sep=',')
attach(seednumber)
names(seednumber)
```

[1] "Country"     "Study.Site"  "Seed.Number"

```
ggplot(seednumber, aes(x = Study.Site, y = Seed.Number, colour = Country,xlab="Study Site", ylab="Number of seeds in a podr" )) + geom_boxplot()
```

Answer (score 0):

`aes` creates a list of unevaulated expressions that describe how variables in the data are mapped to visual properties of geoms.

`xlab` and `ylab` are not counted as visual properties of `geoms`, they are labels for the `scales` that define the `x` and `y` axes.

You can define these in numerous ways

```
# given a base plot
baseplot <- ggplot(seednumber, aes(x = Study.Site, y = Seed.Number, colour = Country)) +
            geom_boxplot()
```

1) The simplest is to use the functions `labs` or `xlab` and `ylab`

```
baseplot + labs(x = "Study Site", y = "Number of seeds in a podr")
# or
baseplot + xlab("Study Site") + ylab("Number of seeds in a podr")
```

note you can use `labs` to change the label of any scale (including those mapped in `aes`)

2). You have more control over the `scales` using the relevant `scale_..._...` functions

eg

```
baseplot + scale_x_discrete(name = "Study Site") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = 'Number of seeds in a podr')
```